# Customize default camera app

Tags: android, camera

Is there any way to add a button or other view to the default camera application? Note that I don't want to create custom camera app but just add a view to the default. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are interested in Custom ROM development.The answer is **NO**

However,you can check out [XDA University](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/getting-started-building-a-kernel-from-source),if you interested in the former.You need to download the source android camera app and make changes to the app..

All these things are called ROM development.But certainly,you wont be able to do something like change something in the default camera app.The above thing would only give you a way to learn how to make your own camera app and may be your own customised android ROM?

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I need as my app has to run on most available ROMs, not only on a custom one though it would be fun to try it. Ok one more thing - I am using intent to start the camera. Can I set parameters regarding the camera settings in that intent and is this supported by most ROMs?

Comment: I believe that you should make your mind regarding what you need to do.Once you mention in the question,that you don't want to develop an app.Then,you say "my app".Anyways,check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html .You can only limit the intent to file size limit.Check out the `Using Existing Camera Apps` section.If my answer has helped you,mark it as an answer.

Comment: I never meant that I want to develop a custom camera app. I only need to know how much I can customize the existing one.My app just needs to take a picture so I don't need to go that deep. Thanks anyways this answers my question.